# Фильтрация элементов поля по общему полю в django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filter

изучаю django, и застрял на вопросе как сделать фильтрацию.

Простая фильтрация с использованием `filter_horizontal = ('field name')` к сожалению мне не подходит, т.к он фильтрует по имени элемента а не по общему полю( 
Нужна примерна такая реализация как это делается `list_filter = ['field name']`, но т.к мое поле указывает инлайново(скрин 1), `list_filter` соответственно не работает.

Пример такой, у меня есть 4 элементов.

1. `name = Белый , material = Дуб`
2. `name = Красный, material = Дуб`
3. `name = пурпурный, material = Метал`
4. `name = глянцевый, material = Метал`

И мне при заполнение в Админки товара надо выдать не общим списком manyToManyField(на скрине есть это поле) и фильтром `filter_horizontal`, который будет фильтровать по name, а нужен фильтр который бы фильтровал по полю `material`, то есть по общему значению(скрин 2, как это реализуется стандартным `list_filter`. Реально ли такое реализовать? может есть какой виджет? Пытался копать в сторону `get_ordering`, но не понимаю как в него каждый раз передавать `material`.

[image: скрин1]

[image: скрин 2]

Модели models.py

```
#модель для вывода inlines у товара
class ImgPropertyMaterialProduct(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   material = models.ForeignKey(MaterialPropery)
   colors = models.ManyToManyField(ImgPropertyMaterial, blank=True, verbose_name='Цвета')

#модель для заполнения property
class ImgPropertyMaterial(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='Позиция для сортировки')
    material = models.ForeignKey(MaterialPropery)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='color', db_index=True,
                            choices=(('color', 'Цвет'), ('texture', 'Текстура')))
    value = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='Значение')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=PhotoPath('color_propery/photo'), null=True, verbose_name='Фото')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Свойство: Изображение материала'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Свойство: Изображение материалов'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

И обычный горизонтальный фильтр в админки

```
class RowInlineTwo(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ImgPropertyMaterialProduct
    filter_horizontal = ('colors',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас очень сумбурный текст вопроса. Я так и не смог понять, что же вам всё таки нужно - `list_filter` или `filter_horizontal`. Если первое, то всё просто:

```
list_filter = ['colors__material']
```

А если надо ограничить элементы доступные в `filter_horizontal`, то чуточку сложнее:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['colors']

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'colors':
            obj_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs['object_id']
            obj = self.get_object(request, obj_id)                
            kwargs['queryset'] = ImgPropertyMaterial.objects.filter(material=obj.material)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте вы правильно поняли по поводу ограничения элементов доступных в filter_horizontal но только мне это надо сделать по полю material и в зависимости от выбраного выше в селекте этого самого материала.

Comment: Если вы ожидаете, что `filter_horizontal`  будет изменять `queryset` динамически - в момент выбора значения в селекте, без нажатия на кнопку сохранения - то это недостижимо средствами Django.

Comment: Да вот как раз таки этого я и ожидал) Но как я понял, ведь можно написать виджет? который бы вешался на селект материала и ajax'ом обновлял поле. Только вот документацию найти про написание виджетов все ни как не могу(

Comment: Если использовать ajax, то одним виджетом не обойдётесь, надо будет ещё вьюхи для него писать. Мне кажется более разумным написать виджет, генерирующий javascript, хранящий в себе массив необходимых данных, обрабатывающий изменения связанного поля и фильтрующий массив по новому значению этого поля. Что-то вроде [этого](https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/schbpno2/1/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз об этом и думал!

Comment: Все таки сделал и обошелся без вьюх, покопался в стандартных виджетах) Еще раз спасибо, и вопрос, можно тут в сообщение выложить решение?

Comment: Конечно можно. Писать ответы на свои же вопросы - это хорошая поактика.