# Связанный dropdown в Django administration

Tags: django, django-admin, model, foreign-key

Идея в том, чтобы при добавлении объявление через админку, выбрав марку машины в следующем dropdown были только те модели машин, которые соответствуют выбранной марке.

Вот models:

```
from django.db import models

class CarBrand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.brand_name


class CarModel(models.Model):
    model_brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)



def __str__(self):
    return self.model_name

class CarPost(models.Model):
    car_post_brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_post_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_post_message = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    car_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.car_post_message
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139368/django-filtering-foreignkey-drop-down-in-admin-interface

Comment: @floydya подозреваю, что автор хочет фильтрации селектов на лету.

Comment: На SO часто возникает этот вопрос. Недавно [отвечал на похожий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/852848/204271). Почитайте комментарии к ответу.